# Is the adjective in this sentence considered for the both following nouns?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

> We intend to consider the global standing of **German universities and
> academic journals.**

Is it clear in the above sentence that the adjective *German* is for both universities and academic journals?

Comment: That implication seems to be there - but such a thing naturally depends on the wider context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ***logically*** obvious, because there's no particular reason why we should correlate the global standing of *academic journals* specifically in conjunction with ***German** universities*.

But the text is ***syntactically*** ambiguous as regards whether adjectival ***German*** extends to the second noun phrase *(**academic journals**)*.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid such ambiguity, without repeating German?

Comment: Why would you want to? As stated, the correct interpretation is obvious, so any further attempt to spell it out could be considered patronising (implying your readers might really lack the common sense to choose the "correct" interpretation). ***Syntactically*** speaking, you could in principle repeat adjectival ***German***, and that might be the best choice in some syntactically similar contexts. But sometimes it might be better to go for more wholesale rephrasing to make the entire sentence more obviously focused on the relevant adjective (which thus applies to all candidate nouns).

Comment: Note that in "algebraic" notation the sense can be conveyed by brackets: *the global standing of German **(universities + academic journals**)*  or ***...(German universities) + (academic journals)***. But English isn't algebra.